# How to hide Event Details in Calendly?

Tags: calendly

I'm embedding Calendly on a web page that includes a form where I collect user information. (I need to collect this info outside of Calendly for a different use case, but also pass it to Calendly.) I'm able to pass the answers to Calendly using the **prefill** object.

Is there a way to hide the "Enter Details" section of Calendly since it's duplicating the information on the form? I tried to set "hide_landing_page_details=1" or "hide_event_type_details=1", but neither seems to work.

Please see the enclosed screenshot for more details. At the top of the page is my form where I collect the info. At the bottom is the Calendly widget.

[image: hide event details in Calendly]

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to hide the booking form details in Calendly. Even if these details are prefilled, the current product requires the person to confirm them in Calendly before submitting.